# HTTP400: GET request doesn't work on Wildfly 18 but works on JBoss 7

Tags: java, get, jboss, wildfly, struts

Recently I upgraded from Jboss 7.1.1 to Wildfly 18.0.0.
On running my ear over wildfly, the following url doesn't work

```
http://localhost:8080/xxx-yyy/contract/subPeriodBlockingPairsAction.do?target=prepareSubPeriodBlockPairs&contractIdSubPeriodId=416|837
```

However the same url works over JBoss 7.1.1 .

The application is struts based. The target method has following syntax-

```
 public ActionForward prepareSubPeriodBlockPairs(final ActionMapping mapping, final ActionForm form, final ActionErrors validationErrors,
        final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
```

I tried putting debug point, which is never reached while debugging on Wildfly.

But reaches while debugging on JBoss.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildfly 18.0 doesn't recognises pipe operator.

Also '|' (pipe) character is unsafe according to the RFC1738 specification of HTTP.

Hence [url encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_urlencode.asp) must be used here to address the issue.